# Local Server using Ubuntu to test web pages - MAMP Alternative

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, lamp, mamp

So I do a lot of web development and I have grown to like using local servers to do my web development. Normally I do web development using Mac OSX, I have a macbook pro. But I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I would like to do development on Ubuntu as well.

The way I manage my data sharing is that I have a "data partition" that is on a ntfs file system, which is where I store my projects. I would like to be able to set apache virtual hosts to these various project directories.

How can I set this up with the correct configuration, and where do I even research to do this?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Comment: @MajidKhan the only problem with those is I've had permission errors with anything that was in a different partition.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu in a virtual machine might have been a better option then.

Comment: That's not really what I want to do, I want the minimalistic part of Ubuntu. I know what I want to do is possible, just requires a little deeper knowledge than I have.

Comment: This might be of some help. http://mac.linux.be/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=95

Answer (score 0):

There is a decent tutorial for installing Apache/MySQL/PHP on Ubuntu here:

http://www.unixmen.com/install-lamp-server-apache-mysql-php-ubuntu-13-10-server/

Bitnami also offer an easy installer that throws in a bunch of other useful stuff igf you prefer:

https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp

Then you will need to read up on virtual hosts in Apache :-

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Comment: What about specific settings for a different partition?

Comment: Virtual hosts can handle that no problems. Have a good look at the doco and examples in the virtual hosts section I pointed to.